# Constructing Regex To Extract Multiple Data

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression to get the Event, Name, School, Final Swim Time, and Swim Threshold (The DIIA) from a Results page like the one at ( http://www.gliac.org/sports/mswimdive/2010-11/stats/Results_Wed_Finals.htm ). Note that the results are sepereated from the rest of the page by the "pre" html tag.

Each "line" looks like this:

```
1 Donahue, Maura            19 INDY                10:39.77   10:03.60 DIIA
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly how to do so. One of the problems (in my mind!) is that sometimes it displays the swimmers age (`19`) and other times it doesn't. In addition, sometimes results show their seed time (`10:39.77`) and other times it only has the final time (`10:03.60`).

I started the regex by trying to split up to the "`,`" in the first name, but failed miserably.

I'm using simple_html to extract the contents of the HTML page.

My code looks like this (I'm using PHP):

```
  $results_url = "http://www.gliac.org/sports/mswimdive/2010-11/stats/Results_Wed_Finals.htm";
// Create a DOM object from a URL
$html = file_get_html($results_url);
if (!$html->find('pre')) {
    $parse_error = "Yes";
}
if (!isset($parse_error)) {    
        $regex = "/[0-9]+(?=[ \s]+)(?=[A-Za-z]+)/";
        $splits = preg_split($regex, $html, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        print_r($splits);    
}
```

If you can help out or point me in the right direction, that would be awesome! Is it even possible to run a regex against the results to extract this data?

Thank you!

Comment: The formatting of this page is pretty static. Have you considered using string manipulation for this? You could take advantage of the fixed-length formatting.

Comment: The code is for a script that will run against any meet result, but the format of the meet results will always be similar to this one - within the pre tags and all. Could you provide me more info on what you are thinking of with string manipulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wont pretend to know what all those numbers mean, but here's something to help start you off with the first line of each person.

```
preg_match_all('/(?P<position>[0-9-]+)\s+(?P<last>[a-z]+)\s*,\s*(?P<first>[a-z]+)\s+((?P<age>[0-9]{2})\s)?(?P<school>[a-z -]+[a-z])\s+(?P<seed>(NT|[0-9:.]+))\s+(?P<final>[0-9:\.]+)\s+(?P<division>[a-z]+)/is', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The regex is very basic and seems to work right now, but when dealing with content you don't have control over, you may want to account for a lot more. For instance, right now that name matching wont work with names that have accented characters or punctuation characters like in the name `O'Reilly`.

Comment: Ran that code, looks like something I can work off of. I'll post again if I can't figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use either preg_match() or preg_match_all()   (see links below)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: preg-match-all does look like it may be a good fit as well, but currently my issue is constructing the regex that would match the pattern